# Node fetch then save to db and res.send

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise, fetch

I do a POST api request to /api/**mycode.js** where inside I'm tryin to:

- do an external API call (using body.value)
- save to db if response is ok
- res.send either "ok", "error", etc back to the original POST request, where I handle it based on the string

I tried using an `async function` inside the `.then` but it doesn't seem to work, this is **mycode.js**:

```
import { connectToDatabase } from "@/utils/mongodb"

const apiKey = process.env.API_KEY
    
export default async function (req, res) {   

        const { db } = await connectToDatabase()

        var token = JSON.stringify(objtoken.accessToken, null, 2)

        if (req.method === 'POST') {
            const body = JSON.parse(req.body)
            let itemId = body.id
                
                // EXTERNAL API
                var url = <external API url query>

                fetch(url, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                    }).then(responseJson => {
                        console.log(responseJson)
                        if (responseJson.status >= 200 && responseJson.status < 300) {
                            saveToDb()
                        }else{
                            throwError()
                        }
                    }).catch(err => {
                        console.log(err)
                });

                const saveToDb = async () => {
                      
                    // save logic for mongodb here
                    await db.collection('mycollection').updateOne etc...

                    res.send({ risp : 'ok' })

                }
                    
                const throwError = () => {
                    res.send({ risp : 'error' })
                }
            
        }

    res.end()
}
```

Comment: Numerous things wrong here.  1 - Does any code actually read the `req.body` from the incoming request to populate it?  If not, it will just be empty.  2 - You send `res.end()` before any of the other code finishes so there's no way for any of the other code to send a response.   3 - You don't log some of the errors so you won't know what is happening if there's an error.

Comment: And, "doesn't seem to work" is NOT an appropriate problem description for a question here.  You need to tell us exactly what doesn't work.  What did you observe?  What did you expect?  What debugging steps did you take to explore and troubleshoot the problem yourself?  Where did you get stuck in your debugging?

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for your reply. 1- Yes req.body is used by var itemId which is then used by the API query below. 2- Should I place a res.end() right below each res.send? 3- I actually did several times but I omitted the logs from the code above, I'll update it with the exact error i get

Comment: If this is Express code, then `res.send()` stands on it's own.  You do NOT call `res.end()` after it.  You only use `res.end()` if you're using `res.write()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 it's Next.js , which uses Express I think, but when I didn't place res.end() it threw a warning that could result in a stall call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call it via `await saveToDb()` or `saveToDb().then()` and not just `saveToDb()` because this is `async` declared function that in case of just calling returns `Promise` that should be `await`ed.

Also instead of using `fetch().then()` you can use `await fetch()` in `try...catch` block that will make code more clear.

```
try {
    const resp = await fetch(...);
    if (resp.status >= 200 && resp.status < 300) {
         await saveToDb();
    } else {
         throwError();
    }
} catch(e) {
    // error
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful since it was concise it made me understand how the logic behind it works. Now it works fine.

Comment: If you would like to make things clear look at this explanation https://javascript.info/async